# Generalized logistic distribution

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, univariate, logistic-distribution

I saw on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_logistic_distribution that when $\alpha<\beta$, generalized type IV logistic distribution can be written as:

$\frac{\exp(-\alpha x)}{(\exp(-x)+1)^\beta}$

But I'm wondering if the case $\alpha\ge\beta$ is studied?

Comment: Could you point out where in that Wikipedia article it requires $\alpha\lt\beta$ for the Type IV distribution?  I cannot see that anywhere.

Comment: If you reparametrize type IV into numerator power and denominator power you'll get this. @whuber

Comment: Now I see the difference.  But notice that this is supposed to be a probability density supported on $x\in\mathbb R:$ what is the integral of this pdf when $\beta \le \alpha$??